# android layout form activity

Tags: android

i am having an xml main.xml,which has few layouts

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/mainl"
   android:tag="aa"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to add one more layout inside the `LinearLayout` from the Activity at Run time. I am able to create Layout in Activity(without using xml) ,but problem in adding this layout to xml at run time ,anyone has a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't add it to the XML at run-time, but you can add it to the layout, which I think is what you want to do.

```
parent.addView(child);
```

Comment: Don't literally type parent.addView(child). `parent` should be your parent layout (e.g. your LinearLayout, referenced by ID), and `child` is the View that you're adding to it.

Comment: now its working after creating ui from activity itself without xml thnks

Answer (score 2):

use the following code

```
LinearLayout parent,child;

child=new LinearLayout(this);

parent=(LinearLayout)findviewById(R.id.mainl);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

parent.addView(child,lp);
```